# Why JQuery $(this) does not work in arrow functions

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am trying to use $(this) so that I can be able to utilize the jQuery object in an arrow but it does not work

```js
$('.btnReserve').click(function(){
        var element_div = $(this).closest('div');
        console.log(element_div.attr('id');
    });
```

works well

but...

```js
$('.btnReserve').click(() => {
        var element_div = $(this).closest('div');
        console.log(element_div.attr('id');
    });
```

`$(this)` does not work

To get the desired outcome I used the method below

```
$('.btnReserve').click((event) => {
        var element_div = $(event.target).closest('div');
        console.log(element_div.attr('id');
    });
```

Comment: Define *does not work*...

Comment: thats is one of the main differences of arrow functions. They maintain the `this` at the time of definition. Just do not use an arrow function if its features do not match the use-case.

Comment: "An arrow function does not have its own `this`".

Comment: Try using document level event listeners

Answer (score 7):

With an arrow function `this` refers to the scope directly outside the scope of the function you created.

With a regular function, this refers to the global scope *or* a bound scope (in your case the jquery object)

Doing `() => {}` is the same as doing `(function () {}).bind(this)`

Try instead to use the event passed to your function

```
$('.btnReserve').click((event) => {
    const element_id = event.target.id;
    console.log(element_id );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight but in my case, I wanted to use the JQuery `$(this)` so that I could be able to utilize the JQuery object with methods like `.parent()` and so on.

Comment: Ok, so don't use an arrow function :-)

Comment: On the edited question above I use the arrow function and it worked

Comment: You could not use this though @SwalehMatongwa

Comment: Explain to me why I should not use that @Neal because the method enables me to select the exact element because `$('.btnReserve')` might match multiple elements but if I use `$(event.target)` I get to select the specific element that has been clicked.